# Decrypting with GPG doesn't create an output file

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I have a PGP file which I usually decrypt using the PGP Corp. app on windows. In trying to get the process working on linux, I've hit a snag. Here's the command I'm using.

```
gpg --output ~/decrypted.txt -d encrypted_report.txt.pgp
```

I'm then prompted for a pass phrase (which gpg accepts) but then... nothing. No output file is created and no errors are displayed.

Toggling verbose mode displays no extra information other than this at the beginning of gpgs output

```
gpg: public key is 11919529
gpg: using subkey 11919529 instead of primary key 4FB1F60F
```

I did import the keyring from windows successfully, but I have no idea what's going on here. I believe the encrypted file may be a PGP-zip file. In trying to extract with the pgp-zip command, I get a tar error (which would make sense, as I'm pretty sure it's a PGP zip file created by the Windows PGP application).

Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you get the original encrypted file onto your Linux system?  Often files get corrupted when transferred if not sent as "binary".  Also, try again using the `--decrypt` option instead of `-d` and try using a complete reference for your output file (instead of ~/).  Finally, you should get at least some message output from gpg; add anything you get to the question.

Comment: I made a small Python script to download the PGP files from an external server. Wouldn't you know it, but the transfer was made in ASCII and not binary. Thank you for the suggestion! Changed it around to binary and decryption worked like a charm.

Comment: Cool, I'll move my comment to an answer so you can wrap this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your original file was downloaded as ASCII such that it was "corrupted" on your Linux system.  When you downloaded the file again using BINARY, your troubles magically disappeared.

This is a very common problem.  Although easy to "fix", it can be hard to uncover.